# How to make generic Entity Framework Core OData query in entity framework database?

Tags: entity-framework-core, odata

I have this code :

```cs
// Create adapter data access, where OrderContext your DbContext
var dataAdapter = new OeEfCoreDataAdapter<model.ordercontext>();

// Create query parser
var parser = new OeParser(new Uri("http://dummy"), dataAdapter, dataAdapter.BuildEdmModelFromEfCoreModel()); 

// Query
var uri = new Uri("http://dummy/Orders?$select=Name");

// The result of the query
var response = new MemoryStream();

// Execute query
await parser.ExecuteGetAsync(uri, OeRequestHeaders.JsonDefault, response, CancellationToken.None);
```

I am getting an error :

> Method not found: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata .iproperty="">Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.EntityTypeExtensions.GetDeclaredProperties(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IEntityType)'.

Comment: OData is a protocol implemented by various libraries. The classes you posted aren't in any of the ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core libraries. What are these, and what are you trying to do?

Comment: I got this code from below Article:-https://codingsight.com/odatatoentity-an-easy-way-to-create-net-core-odata-services/ , I want to make generic Odata Query so that it goes to Enity framework database and get matching  results, Please note : We want to specify table name , column name in Odata Query , Basically it is related to OData Entity framework core , Please advise any other article.@ Panagiotis Kanavos